# How can KDiff3 be used properly with TortoiseSVN to resolve conflicts?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, conflict

I have TortoiseSVN set up to use KDiff3 as the conflict resolution tool (I find it shows more information useful to the merge than the built-in TortoiseMerge does).

When I open a file with Tortoise's "Edit Conflicts" command it shows me the three files and I have to select "Merge->Merge Current File" manually. The problem is that KDiff3 saves the result to `source_file.working` instead of to `source_file`. So without doing a Save As, the real file with the conflict doesn't get modified. Is there a way around doing this manual Save As every time?

I know this isn't strictly a programming question but it's about an ancillary process common enough to programmers that it should be useful here. I couldn't find the answer to this elsewhere.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Mine is a bit longer:

```
"C:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe" %base %mine %theirs -o %merged --L1 Base --L2 Mine --L3 Theirs
```

Comment: So it is! And since I'm not entitled to the answer credit for this question, and you were more comprehensive, here you go.

Comment: I find that (for me at least) the labels can be set to something which is (occasionally) more helpful thus:-

--L1 "Base: %base" --L2 "Mine: %mine" --L3 "Theirs: %theirs"

Comment: This works. Is there a way to make it so when you close KDiff3 editor that it marks the conflict  as resolved? Maybe there is a use-case that makes it beneficial to do something before you manually choose "Mark as resolved", but it would be nice to not have that last step.

Comment: @EdRandall Yours fails when `%mine` or `%theirs` contains whitespace, it tries to open a 3-way merge instead of a diff. Possibly because the content of `%mine` and `%theirs` is wrapped in `"` quotes.

Comment: Please give me a command which will work in tortoise git rebase function. I was merged and saved changes in file. But file is still conflict. When I second time open merge, there are any changes which I made. If I click reload, my changes are gone too.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I just needed a more specific command line. I had it set simply to the path to `kdiff3.exe`, and hoped the default arguments passed from TortoiseSVN would be enough. Not so. Here's the one needed (the key being the `-o` argument):

```
C:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe %base %theirs %mine -o %merged
```

Answer (score 5):

In case there's someone else like me, let me point out his is done in TortoiseSVN->Settings->Diff Viewer. I installed KDiff3 in Windows with Tortoise already installed and it got configured automatically. It took me some time to figure out where this needed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but could solve it without any command line:
when I clicked "Edit Conflicts" kdiff3 opend up. 
After solving the conflict I simply clicked "save" and closed the kdiff3 window. 
After the window was closed I switched back to the SVN "resolve confict"- window and clicked resolved.
Then the next conflict popped up....