# Saving merges using KDiff3 with TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, kdiff3

Wanting to use KDiff3 as my conflict resolution tool for TortoiseSVN I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200657/19977) and [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-progs) to configure TortoiseSVN to use KDiff3. My merge tool settings in TortoiseSVN are thus:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe %base %mine %theirs -o %merged --L1 %bname --L2 %yname --L3 %tname
```

When performing a merge a conflicts may be detected. If they are I hit the 'Edit Conflict'  button to launch KDiff3 and reconcile the merge conflicts.

However, when I save my merge the result is saved to a temporary file in the .svn folders rather than within the actual working file `C:\projects\my-new-project\src\mvags1.mxml`. The temporary location can be seen in the KDiff3 output window as well.

[image]

Have I configured anything incorrectly or are my expectations for how KDiff3 works with TortoiseSVN incorrect?

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.7.5 and KDiff3 0.9.96.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My expectations for how KDiff3 would work with TortoiseSVN and Subversion were flawed. The behavior that I was experiencing is the correct behavior.

The proper process for using KDiff3 with TortoiseSVN is:

1. Click the edit conflicts button when conflicts are detected (in TortoiseSVN)
2. Resolve the merge with KDiff3
3. Click the save button in KDiff3
4. Close KDiff3
5. In TortoiseSVN mark the file as resolved

Answer (score 0):

After merge to working copy of a branch (svn merge --quiet --accept postpone http://../trunk)

- I go to TortoiseSVN extension menu and select "Resolve..."
  The window with the list of conflicted items displayed.
- Right click on the first item and then select "Edit conflicts". KDiff3 merge window appears.
- Pressing B for selecting line source.
- click Save. File will be saved with merge result.
- Close KDiff3.

**How to make conflict automatically  marked as resolved in TortoiseSVN when I exiting KDiff3?**

I am using:

- Windows 10 x64
- TortoiseSVN 1.9.5, Build 27581 - 64 Bit
- kdiff3 Version 0.9.98 (64 bit)
- Merge Tool setting in TortoiseSVN
  C:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe %base %mine %theirs -o %merged --L1 Base --L2 Mine --L3 Theirs